# Issue with static member function and derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, static-methods

I have a class with static member function (which is necessary). To be able to use non-static members of the class. I defined a `Static_This` which is a pointer to the class.

```
template<class T>
class Energy_Minimizer
{
protected:

    static Energy_Minimizer* Static_This;

    Petsc_Vector<T>* Gradient;
    Petsc_Vector<T>* Solution;
    static int Form_Function_and_Gradient(Petsc_Vector<T> *Solution_,Petsc_Vector<T>  *Gradient_, PetscReal *Function_Value_);
public:
    Energy_Minimizer(MPI_Comm Communicator_);
    void Add_Term(vector<int>& Indexes, void* Coefs, string Function_Name_);
    virtual void Total_Energy()=0;
};
```

I set the `Static_This` in the constructor of the class.

```
template<>
Energy_Minimizer<double>::Energy_Minimizer(MPI_Comm Communicator_)
{
    Communicator = Communicator_;
    Static_This = this;
        ...
}
```

And can access to non-static virtual function:

```
int Energy_Minimizer<double>::Form_Function_and_Gradient(Petsc_Vector<double> *Solution_,Petsc_Vector<double>  *Gradient_, PetscReal *Function_Value_)
{

Static_This->Solution = Solution_;
    Static_This->Gradient = Gradient_;

    // Call the user-defined routine to construct the function value, gradient
    Static_This->Total_Energy();

    return 0;
}
```

I implement the virtual function Total_Energy() in the derived class:

```
class Strain_Solver : public Energy_Minimizer<double>;

void Strain_Solver::Total_Energy()
{
        ****** Here problem occurs ******
    this->Add_Term(ij_Indexes, NULL , string("Alpha_Term")); 
}
```

I call the function of the base class from derived class virtual function. The only problem I have is that as soon as I call a member function of the base class from my derived class then the data (here Solution) gets corrupted. i.e. When I call Add_Term function in above example the Solution vector of the base class suddenly gets corrupted. It is like it gets de-allocated.

Comment: `Static_This` is not `static`. How can you access it in a static function? It seems you have not posted the actual post. THAT is one problem. If you're doing something, and posting something else, and expecting us to help you?

Comment: It was a typo in the question, I am correcting it

Comment: What you are trying to do here seems like an atrocity. Think on it some more and redesign your code. Maybe private inheritance could solve your problems?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem originates in the derived class, and with this kind of design it could be anywhere. You don't seem to be using any language constructs for the intended purpose… you're breaking all the rules and it's not clear why.

> When I call Add_Term function in above example the Solution vector of the base class suddenly gets corrupted. It is like it gets de-allocated.

Ignoring the code, when you increase the size of a `std::vector`, it may reallocate (that is, *deallocate* and move) the contained objects to a larger memory block. Therefore you can't use pointers or iterators into a `std::vector` whose size increases.

If some part of the program keeps track of a thing inside `ij_Indexes` across a call to `Add_Term`, it must

- Use integer offsets (`std::size_t` is the best type) and the subscript operator (syntax like `ij_Indexes[offset]`) or
- The type of `ij_Indexes` should be changed to the container `std::deque`, which doesn't reallocate but isn't a flat array and would be incompatible with a C-based math library such as you appear to be using.

Comment: The Gradient is not an std::vector, it is a wrapper class. Moreover, the problem occurs when I call this->Add_Term(ij_Indexes, NULL , string("Alpha_Term")); in its first line which I'm not doing anything.

Comment: It is like when you exit a function and all the local variables of function gets freed, but I don't know why it happens here.

Comment: @Hesam The answer still stands, edited. This is all a bit of a shot in the dark, I'm just mentioning a common mistake that happens to match with the symptom you describe. The error could well be something else, and it's likely this site can't help you. But do look into this possibility.

Comment: What do you mean with this kind of design? What would be a better design?

Answer (score 0):

Your Static_This member is not static. Even if it were, there's only one instance of a static field (data member), but there can be multiple instances of a class. Which instance would your Static_This member point to?

It seems like an odd design anyway. If you post your real code (or at least describe it), I'm sure someone will suggest you a better design.